# Why is Node fs.writeFile() method successful, but an empty file is then sent to the browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fs

The following callback function sends an empty file to the browser even though the file contains 'helloworld' on the server:

```
router.get('/Download', function(req, res) {
    var fs = require('fs')
    fs.writeFile('helloworld.txt', 'helloworld');
    res.download('helloworld.txt');
})
```

Comment: Programming with Node.JS is asynchronous programming. You should get use with that, if you want to get the maximum of Node.js.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`writeFile` is asynchronous.
either use it as:

```
fs.writeFile('helloworld.txt', 'helloworld', function () {
    res.download('helloworld.txt');
});
```

or use `writeFileSync`

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback

Comment: can you please explain why isn't asynchronous method is working?

Comment: Long story short `writeFile` might take a while to execute in completion.  `res.download` will execute before the writeFile is completed. At the moment it executes the file is empty. 
It is due to a javascript (nodejs) construct the event loop. You can read about it in the 2 following links and I recommend to look for more source based on how you learn better, e.g. youtube videos, interactive learning, etc. https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/#header-setimmediate-vs-settimeout & https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop#Event_loop

Answer (score 0):

Try to find out if your code has

> process.exit()

for some reason. If you do, comment out this one and you will be good to go. My version is v8.6.0.

See also: 
[node - fs.writeFile creates a blank file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31572484/node-fs-writefile-creates-a-blank-file/46553335#46553335)