# Console log shows message but nothing in file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to save output to a file. I can see the error message from server in console.log (see bellow) but for some reason it's not written in file. The file is empty. Any ideas?

```js
const fileName = `response ${data.item.name}.json`; // create file from response of each request 
const content = data.response.stream.toString(); // content of response   
console.log("JSON response: ", content);


fs.writeFile(fileName, content, function(error) { // The file itself
  if (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
});
```

What I see in console log:
I need that "JSON response" be in file

```
→ Create pce_test
  POST http://<<server>>:<<port>>/apiv2/servers  JSON response:  Error creating Integration Server: server name in use
[409 Conflict, 886B, 82ms]
```

[image: OUtput in visual studio]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [node - fs.writeFile creates a blank file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31572484/node-fs-writefile-creates-a-blank-file)

Comment: @epascarello I've tried fs.writeFileSync too. No success. This happens just in one case, otherwise I am able to write into file. There must be problem somewhere else.

Comment: So what is special about this "case" then?

Comment: My guess is you need to show us more code than what you have shown us.

Comment: Seems like you already have the file under that name try to delte the file before creating or try unique name

Answer (score 0):

The content has to be in the JSON format, if you want to write a JSON file.

```
const content = `{"key": "${data.response.stream.toString()}"}`; // content of response
```

If you want to write the object properties in a new line with a tab, you can use something like below;

```
const content = JSON.stringify(`{\n \t "key": "${data.response.stream.toString()}"\n}`); 
fs.writeFile(fileName, JSON.parse(content), (error) => { // The file itself
  if (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
});
```